# ValueError in optparse when using type

Tags: python, python-2.7, optparse

I've been given a script that uses optparse. I'm not familiar with this module, so I've been reading up on it and trying various simple exercises to get a better understanding of how it works. The code below is giving me a ValueError, telling me 'int' is not callable. It runs fine if I don't use the type option. Is this correct, or am I missing something?

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Non-optional')

parser.add_argument('count', action='store', type="int")
parser.add_argument('units', action='store')

print parser.parse_args()
```

Called from command line as: python.exe module1.py 3, Test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`type` parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#type) has to be an actual type, not the name of a type.

```
parser.add_argument('count', action='store', type=int)
```

Note that I removed the `"` around `int`.

Comment: Thanks. I'd tried that as well, but got an 'invalid int value' error. I used quotes because that's how it looks in the python docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html?highlight=type#standard-option-types. Anyway, you are correct; my error was adding a comma after the 3. Thanks.